# При загрузке видео в БД (локальный сервер) возникает ошибка Trying to get property 'name' of non-object YII2

Tags: php, yii2

view

```
<?php \yii\bootstrap4\ActiveForm::begin([
            'options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']
        ]) ?>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
            Вибрати файл
            <input type="file" id="videoFile" name="video">
        </button>

        <?php \yii\bootstrap4\ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

**controller**

```
<?php

namespace backend\controllers;

use common\models\Video;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

/**
 * VideoController implements the CRUD actions for Video model.
 */
class VideoController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return array_merge(
            parent::behaviors(),
            [
                'verbs' => [
                    'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                    'actions' => [
                        'delete' => ['POST'],
                    ],
                ],
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Lists all Video models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => Video::find(),
            /*
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 50
            ],
            'sort' => [
                'defaultOrder' => [
                    'video_id' => SORT_DESC,
                ]
            ],
            */
        ]);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single Video model.
     * @param string $id Video ID
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Video model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {

        $model = new Video();
        $model->video = UploadedFile::getInstancesByName('video');

        if (\Yii::$app->request->isPost && $model->save()){
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->video_id]);
        }
        return $this->render('create', ['model' => $model,]);
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing Video model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param string $id Video ID
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public
    function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->video_id]);
        }

        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

Model

```
<?php

namespace common\models;

use Yii;
use yii\helpers\FileHelper;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "{{%video}}".
 *
 * @property string $video_id
 * @property string $title
 * @property string|null $description
 * @property string|null $tags
 * @property int|null $status
 * @property int|null $has_thumbnail
 * @property string|null $video_name
 * @property int|null $created_at
 * @property int|null $updated_at
 * @property int|null $created_by
 *
 * @property User $createdBy
 */
class Video extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @var UploadedFile
     */
    public $video;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{{%video}}';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['video_id', 'title'], 'required'],
            [['description'], 'string'],
            [['status', 'has_thumbnail', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'created_by'], 'integer'],
            [['video_id'], 'string', 'max' => 16],
            [['title', 'tags', 'video_name'], 'string', 'max' => 512],
            [['video_id'], 'unique'],
            [['created_by'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => User::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['created_by' => 'id']],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'video_id' => 'Video ID',
            'title' => 'Title',
            'description' => 'Description',
            'tags' => 'Tags',
            'status' => 'Status',
            'has_thumbnail' => 'Has Thumbnail',
            'video_name' => 'Video Name',
            'created_at' => 'Created At',
            'updated_at' => 'Updated At',
            'created_by' => 'Created By',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Gets query for [[CreatedBy]].
     *
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery|\common\models\query\UserQuery
     */
    public function getCreatedBy()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'created_by']);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @return \common\models\query\VideoQuery the active query used by this AR class.
     */
    public static function find()
    {
        return new \common\models\query\VideoQuery(get_called_class());
    }

    /**
     * @param bool $runValidation
     * @param null $attributeNames
     * @return bool
     */
    public function save($runValidation = false, $attributeNames = null)
{
    $isInsert = $this->isNewRecord;
    if ($isInsert){
        $this->video_id = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString(8);
        $this->title = $this->video->name; // вот здесь в обработчике показывает ошибку
        $this->video_name = $this->video->name; // также здесь
    }
    $saved = parent::save($runValidation, $attributeNames);
    if (!$saved){
        return false;
    }
    if ($isInsert){
        $videoPath = Yii::getAlias('@frontend/web/storage/videos/'.$this->video_id.'.mp4');
        if (!is_dir(dirname($videoPath))){
            FileHelper::createDirectory(dirname($videoPath));
        }
        $this->video->saveAs($videoPath);
    }
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: Вам надо показать  нам свойство модели, rules модели и геттеры, где хоть как-то упоминается слово video

Comment: Загрузил модель и контроллер

Comment: вам надо воспользоваться отладкой и посмотреть что у вас в `UploadedFile::getInstancesByName`  возможно там ошибка вываливается или имя неправильное

Comment: при загрузке файла отображается NULL

Comment: Ну оберни конструкцию в try/catch может увидишь ошибку. Получается проблема именно в данной строчке

Comment: Например в форме у поля не то имя

Comment: Пробовал и try/catch и var_dump. Отображается Null или пустой массив. Хотя иногда, хочу подметить, один пдф файл отображался. Но только он, остальные null

Comment: Не грузиться именно видео файлы. Пдф файлы, ворд файлы, mp3 загружаются без ошибок

Answer (score 0):

При передаче данных методом Post, передается не объект, а массив. О чем и сообщает тебе ошибка. Обратитсь так:

```
$this->title = $this->video['name'];
```

И сделай var_dump($video);
И все увидишь